# i want to confirm json data received

Tags: java, json

i have to do simple project i received

iot Sensor Monitor send json data to my server domain(localhost:8080/prism/iot.do)

---

### TCP receive data details

POST /qbsiotpost HTTP/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: 192.168.1.189:8888
User-Agent: WFS
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 181

{ "devicedesc":"myhome","deviceid":2436009, "datetime":1589434210, "temperature":27.4, "humidity":41.3, "EC": 2 }

i want to confirm this data in java class

What am I supposed to do?

@Controller
public class iot {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/iot.do"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public void verifyiot(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody iotVO iotvo) throws Exception {

```
    System.out.println("kkkk >>>" + iotvo.getDatetime());
    



    
}
```

}

i call localhost:8080/prism/iot.do

result

below this error
error:Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Comment: What do you mean by _confirm_?

Comment: Make sure data is coming in controller properly..

Comment: Assuming that you have some code written (that what actually is the _controller_) you could implemnt some validation for it? :thinking:

Comment: You need to use @RequestMapping( consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.